# Multipart/form-data and boundary. Need help in streaming the data at server end

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, stream, multipart

I have multipart/form-data request from client side which will upload multiple files. Each file would be a large file (more than 10MB in size). I want to receive each file individually and process it while remaining files are still getting received completely.

This is my request in rest console
URL : http://localhost:8080/multiUpload
Content-Type : multipart/form-data;boundary=myboundary
form-data : two attachments

This is my snippet of code to handle it.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/multiUpload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String handleMultiFileUpload(HttpServletRequest request)
            throws IOException {
        System.out.println("======Inside handleFileUpload======");
        try {
            MultipartStream multipartStream = new MultipartStream(
                    request.getInputStream(), "myboundary".getBytes(),
                    1024 * 1024, null);
            boolean nextPart = multipartStream.skipPreamble();
            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            while (nextPart) {
                System.out.println("inside while");
                multipartStream.readBodyData(outputStream);
                InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                        outputStream.toByteArray());
                nextPart = multipartStream.readBoundary();
            }
        } catch (MultipartStream.MalformedStreamException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "You successfully uploaded !";
    }
```

The code is not entering into while loop. i.e skipPreamble is returning false. Am I doing anything wrong ??.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I'm having a very similar problem with multipart/form-data which I haven't been able to solve yet.

Comment: Hi guys, did you come up with any solution or workaround?